# how to sort an array of string which contains special characters and white spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, special-characters

I Want to sort an array of string which contains special characters and white spaces. While sorting i want to ignore special characters , so that sorting of array happens based on only characters and digits.

for example : array would be like:
 **["ibtp-17","personal (z)","personal (a)","(z)","yabcd","y(3)"]**

just need smart logic to implement this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

---

so far i have tried using replace which gives me some times correct result and some times not.

```
 ["ibtp-17","personal (z)","personal (a)","(z)","yabcd","y(3)"]
 .sort(function(a,b){
    return a.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "") > b.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "")
 })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort()`takes a comparison function.

Comment: so far i have tried using replace which gives me some times correct result and some times not.    ` ["ibtp-17","personal (z)","personal (a)","(z)","yabcd","y(3)"].sort(function(a,b){return a.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "")>b.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "")})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not supposed to just post code (since the OP needs to attempt something by themselves first and all that jazz). Here's some logic:

`Array.sort()` takes a comparison function. In said comparison function you can put some regex based special character stripper like `String.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");`. and then compare the resultant strings. Cheers.

Comment: i tried  with your suggested approach, but it didn't seems to be working with this array. `["Personal (in progress)","Personal (finished)","district","ibtp-17","intelligence"].sort(function(a,b){return a.replace(/[0-9a-zA-Z ]/g,"")>b.replace(/[0-9a-zA-Z ]/g,"")})` . **please copy this and run in your console**

Comment: Try running `["P", "i"].sort()`, or, for that matter, `"P">"i"` in console..it will become obvious to you why that is resulting in an error.

Comment: Easiest way to fix that issue would be to call `.toLowerCase()` on the strings first